# How to use an array-based form with the FormData object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to use the new FormData element to convert a form into one (nested) JSON string.

This is the example form structure:

1. name
2. nested[key]
3. nested[key2]
4. nested[key3]

Using the following code, I'll get one flat JSON object, not the nested version.

```js
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("testForm"));
    var object = {};
    formData.forEach(function(value, key){
        object[key] = value;
    });
    var json = JSON.stringify(object);
    return json;
```

Result:

```
{"name":"test","nested[key]":"test","nested[key2]":"test","nested[key3]":"test"}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate desired output?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to achieve the following result:
```{"name":"test","nested":["key":"test","key2":"test","key3":"test"]}```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the FormData documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

In my example below I've used the entries() method and I've converted it to an array be able to use the forEach method and build the object.

```js
// Get the form
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
// Create FormData object
var formData = new FormData(myForm);

// Loop through the entries and append to the object
var result = {};
Array.from(formData.entries()).forEach(function(entr) {
  var key = entr[0];
  var value = entr[1];
  result[key] = value;
});

// Print the result
console.log(result);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
Name <input name="name" value="a"/>
</form>
```

Comment: HI Stefan, thanks for your comment. I've adjusted it a bit more, to get the correct nesting levels in the JSON output. I had to split it on ```if (entr[0].includes('[')) {```, otherwise I use the result[key] mapping.

Answer (score -1):

you can try `set` with lodash:

```js
import { set } from 'lodash';

var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("testForm"));
var object = {};
formData.forEach(function(value, key){
    set(object, key, value);
});
```

set document here: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.14#set

Comment: Might be a little bit overkill, to include lodash (or other libraries) for such a small problem.

Comment: @StefanKoenen it's not a small problem, you need to handle some complex case, for example, an array field: `name=foo[][bar]`. If you think `lodash` is big, you can try `lodash.set`, or write a function to process it~